# Badge value on "More" tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar, badge

I am making an iOS app which has a tabBarController, with more than 5 tabs. Thus, first four are directly clickable and the rest come under MORE tab.

I want to show a badge on the MORE tab if there is any badge for the tabs that are hidden inside this MORE tab.

I know about how to do that from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387401/how-to-add-a-badge-to-the-system-generated-more-uitabbaritem).

But the order of my tabs is configurable. Is there a way I can configure the MORE tab such it just puts the badgeValue if I set a value for a tab inside it?

I am thinking of this:

```
- (void)updateBadgeValue:(NSInteger)count {
    int index = [self.tabBarController indexOfObject:self.tabBarItem];
    if (index > 4) { //Inside MORE tab
        [[[self.tabBarController moreTabBarController] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count]];
    }
    //Also setting badge of self.tabbarItem so that it remains when it is brought to "hot tab items".
}
```

I am looking for a solution such that I dont have to do that for every tab. Also, if the tab order is changed by the user, the badgeValue should also update accordingly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this:

```
- (void)updateBadgeValue:(NSInteger)count {
    int index = [self.tabBarController indexOfObject:self.tabBarItem];
    if (index > 4) {
        int moreTabCount = count + [[[[self.tabBarController moreTabBarController] tabBarItem] badgeValue] intValue];
        [[[self.tabBarController moreTabBarController] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", moreTabCount]];
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** You can respond to configuration changes by using

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didEndCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers changed:(BOOL)changed
```

delegate method in your `UITabBarController`'s delegate (it should be `AppDelegate`). Let's do it:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didEndCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers changed:(BOOL)changed {
    if(changed) {
        int count = 0;
        int i; for(i = 4; i < [viewControllers count]; i++)
            count += [[[[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] tabBarItem] badgeValue] intValue];
        if(count > 0)
            [[self.tabBarController moreTabBarController] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count]];
    }
}
```

I think that it will work.

Comment: Thanks Kashiv. This is just about "adding" to the available count. I am also looking for updating when tab order changes. On a side node, the correct statement would be `.. moreTabCount = [... badgeValue] intValue];` since badgeValue is a NSString.

Comment: I think I'll have to do that only. There doesn't seem to be any API that takes care of this stuff automatically. I mean the MORE tab is created by the system itself, so it should manage this tab too :P.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
[[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] 
          objectAtIndex:4] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",yourBadgeValue];
```

Here `ObjectAtIndex` is for your Tab where 0 represents your first tab etc...

Comment: Please read the complete post. I know how to put a badge value on more tab. I want to know to get it in sync with MY tabs.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use for Swift 4:**

let messagesCount: Int = 5
self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = " \(messagesCount)"