# How to set the badge on moreNavigationController item programatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I can set Badge for Tab Bar Item in IB[image]

and it appear in more menu like this [image]

But I can not set/change it from the view controller when its located in "more menu".

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you'd like to implement also a badge in your dedicated view controller title? If that's the case you need to implement your own badge.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457307/3883492